# Spring Security OAuth2 Client SSO with Resource Owner Password Credentials and JWT

Tags: spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement authentication using spring security oauth2 with JsonWebToken.

For external apps I plan to use the "Authorization Code Grant Flow" but for a trusted frontend we want to use the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow".

The JWT should be held in the session of the UI server - also the UI server holds the client credentials - they are not exposed to the client. So the user logs in against the UI server. The server uses the token endpoint of the auth server to request a JsonWebToken, converts it to a OAuth2Authentication and stores it in the SecuritContextHolder.

I implemented this using a custom controller login method. But I would like to be able to use `@EnableOauth2Sso` and avoid the custom implementation. I saw several examples of how to do this with the "Authorization Code Grant Flow" - e.g this one https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ - but there is nothing regarding documentation and tutorials for the "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow".

Any hints?